# URL not loaded within Kaizala - IOS

Tags: ios, kaizala

I am trying to load url within Kaizala using iframe. It works fine in Android. But in IOS the app redirects it to browser. I also tried it using embed tag. Can anybody help me fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to load http url. In iOS, its open in external browser.
Try with https url. It should open within the iFrame.

Comment: No. I loaded https url. Even https:www.facebook.com is also loading in external browser in IOS.